# How can I have a fixed div next to a parent div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a div with a button next to a parent div. Like this:

```
____________
|relative  |
|          |
|          |
|          |_______
|          | fixed |
|          |_______|
|          |
|          |
|__________|
```

The fixed div has to be fixed during scrolling but at all time next to the parent and not under or above its parent.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have anything you've tried previously? If so - can you post your code.

Comment: "fixed" means it never moves if u scroll the page
"absolute" means, it moves when the page scrolls but adding elements will not trouble its position
What do u want ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that the element with `position: fixed` is always relative to the body. It behaves differently from elements with `position: absolute`, which is relative to parent element with `position: relative` declared.

So the main problem is, that if you set `left` to the fixed element, it sticks to left edge of body element, even if it's parent is positioned relative. **But** you could use a trick, and skip `left` declaration for fixed element.

```css
.main {
    /*just for visualisation*/
    width: 300px;
    height: 1500px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.main, .fake-wrapper {
    float: left;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<!-- your content -->
</div>
<div class="fake-wrapper">
    <div class="fixed">
        <a href="/">click!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GFAyJ/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `position:fixed` for the second div

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    zx
</div>
<div class="fix">
    <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0
}
.main{
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    background:grey;
}
.fix{
     position:fixed;
     top:50%;
     border:red solid 2px;
     background:yellow;
     left:50%
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jAg7M/1/)**

Comment: Allright, I made the button fixed but how to "attach" it next to parent div. Is there a way with jQuery?

Comment: @MmynameStackflow As I dont know how is your html structure, could you post your working demo

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for `position: absolute`, not fixed -- if your parent has the class `parent` and the button has the class `button`, what you need is similar to (assuming button has a fixed width of 100px for this):

```
.parent { position: relative; }
.button { position: absolute; top: 45%; right: -100px; }
```

here's an example fiddle (added some width/heights to demonstrate, these should come from your content instead) http://jsfiddle.net/WpnP4/

**Edit:** just realized the question is not 100% clear -- I assumed you wanted the button to be next to a specific element and scroll with the screen. Use `position:fixed` if you want the button element to stay fixed in the screen.