# How can I implement a fixed sidebar?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a situation like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        #wrapper { width: 1100px; margin: 0px auto; }
        #wrapper #stream { width: 790px; float: left; border: 1px solid red;  }
        #wrapper aside { width: 270px; float: left;  border: 1px solid red; }
    </style>
    <body>
        <section id="wrapper">
            <section id="stream">
                some text...
            </section>
            <aside>
                <ul>    
                    <li>something</li>
                    <li>something</li>
                    <li>something</li>
                    <li>something</li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I don't want the sidebar to move even if the page scrolls down.

I tried setting the aside's position to fixed but so I can't set properly the distance from left.

I found a solution with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $("aside").css('top', $(window).scrollTop()+'px');
    });
})
```

but with Chrome and Safari the scroll of the aside is piecewise.

Any help?

========================

**SOLUTION:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <style>
    #wrapper {

        width: 1100px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    #stream {
      width: 800px;
      background: #ccc;
      float: left;
    }
    #sidebar {
    float: left;
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 200px;
    }
    aside {
      position: fixed;
      top: 20px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <section id="wrapper">
        <section id="stream">
                some text...
        </section>
        <section id="sidebar">
          <aside>
                <ul>    
                    <li>something</li>
                    <li>something</li>
                    <li>something</li>
                    <li>something</li>
                </ul>
          </aside>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why the fixed position didn't work? Can you show the CSS you tried and tell us why you didn't get it to work? (Note that you can edit your question to add details.)

Comment: If you have problem with setting proper distance from left, just don;t set it. Ithink it might be similar to [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430320/fixed-div-next-to-parent-div/15431083#15431083).

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` properties, you have to set the object's `display` property to `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.

Either way, by setting `position: fixed;` it won't move when you scroll.

Comment: I think that setting `position: fixed` **will move element** when scrolling.

Comment: Thanks to nd_macias I've found a simple solution that works for me! I have added it to the question.

Comment: @nd_macias uuhhm... no. `position: fixed` will fix an element on the screen. `position: absolute` will allow you to set an element relative from it's parent, and `position: relative` sets an element relative from it's current position.

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxNdD/).

Comment: @Tim S. Ok, I guess there's a bit of misunderstanding, because that is exactly what I mean by "it will move", although I meant "it will move relatively to other elements". :)

Comment: @nd_macias I am very confused right now :p

Comment: @Tim S. What I meant is that we both meant the same. :)